# what is the fastest way to populate SQLite table from a datatable

Tags: c#, sqlite

What is the fastest way to populate a SQLite database from a DataTable in C# .net 2.

Currently I am building insert statments for each row in the table. I have tried a dataadaptor but the speed didn't seem to be any faster. It currently takes 5 min to loop through 20,000 rows and write them to the database.
Any sugestions?

solution:

I found that surounding blocks of insert statments with BEGIN...COMMIT worked for me with a remarkable speed improvement:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO friends (name1,name2) VALUES  ('john','smith');
INSERT INTO friends (name1,name2) VALUES  ('jane','doe');
COMMIT;
```

my insert statements were around 500 byte each, so I limited the number of statements to 100 per transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this FAQ entry from the SQLite website:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

By default, each INSERT statement is its own transaction. But if you surround multiple INSERT statements with BEGIN...COMMIT then all the inserts are grouped into a single transaction. The time needed to commit the transaction is amortized over all the enclosed insert statements and so the time per insert statement is greatly reduced.

Comment: interesting. I wonder how many   statments to surround with the BEGIN ... COMMIT block

Comment: You can do sixty transactions per second with a 7200 RPM hard drive. Divide your write speed (say 5MB/s) by 60 to get the number of bytes per transaction, and then divide that by your record size to get the number of inserts per transaction.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/134.aspx).

The best way is to use `ExecuteNonQuery()`, which commits all the inserts at once, and doesn't have to keep allocating strings.  20,000 rows should take much less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the SqLiteDataAdapter. (I still have to use vb.net but following example should be ease to translate. Or have a look at the original source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2671511)

```
Private Sub FillDatabaseTableWithDataTable(dataTable As DataTable)
            ' inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/2671511

            ' Query the destination database
            Dim query As String = $"SELECT * FROM `{dataTable.TableName}`"

            Using adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(query, Connection)

                Using commandBuilder = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter)

                    Connection.Open()

                    commandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["
                    commandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
                    commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand()

                    'Create an empty "destination" table for synchronization
                    ' with SqLite "source" database
                    Dim destinationTable As New DataTable()

                    'load data from SqLite "source" database to destination table, e.g.
                    'column headers
                    adapter.Fill(destinationTable)

                    'adapt "destination" table: fill data
                    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
                        Dim destinationRow As DataRow = destinationTable.NewRow()
                        destinationRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray
                        destinationTable.Rows.Add(destinationRow)
                    Next

                    'Update SqLite source table
                    'the Update has To be wrapped In a transaction
                    'Otherwise, SQLite would implicitly create a transaction
                    'for each line. That would slow down the writing process.
                    Using transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction()
                        adapter.Update(destinationTable)
                        transaction.Commit()
                    End Using

                    Connection.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Sub
```